# C# Query MS-Access Table and place read values from column in a text box

Tags: c#, ms-access-2010

Below is a snapshot of my code.  I am trying to access the only column in the customer table and place the values into a textbox on the form.  I keep getting the error with my code `"InvalidOperationException was unhandled"` at the line declaring `dr` as a `OleDbDataReader` object.

1. What do I have wrong with the below code that would be giving me this error?
2. Should I do a list to pick out the text I want from the database?
3. How can I return the column values from access into a list in C# so that I can search the list for a particular value?

   ```
   string strsql = "Select * from Customer";
   OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();

   cmd.CommandText = strsql;
   conn.Open();

   OleDbDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();



   while(dr.Read())
   {
       textBox1.Text += dr["Customer"].ToString();
   }
   conn.Close();
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A command carries the info to be executed, a connection carries the info to reach the database server. The two objects should be linked together to produce any result. You miss that line

```
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
cmd.CommandText = strsql;
cmd.Connection = conn; // <= here
conn.Open();
```

Remember also that *disposable* objects like a command, a reader and a connection should be *disposed* immediately after usage. For this pattern exists the using statement

So you should write

```
string cmdText = "Select * from Customer";
using(OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(.....constring...))
using(OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(cmdText, conn))
{
    conn.Open();
    using(OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while(reader.Read())
           .....
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is some sample code.

```
try
            {
                using (OleDbConnection myConnection = new OleDbConnection())//make use of the using statement 
                {
                    myConnection.ConnectionString = myConnectionString;
                    myConnection.Open();//Open your connection
                    OleDbCommand cmdNotReturned = myConnection.CreateCommand();//Create a command 
                    cmdNotReturned.CommandText = "someQuery";
                    OleDbDataReader readerNotReturned = cmdNotReturned.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
                        // close conn after complete
                    // Load the result into a DataTable
                    if (readerNotReturned != null) someDataTable.Load(readerNotReturned);
               }
            }
```

After that you have a Datatable containing your data. Ofcourse you can afterwards search for records in the Datatable any way you like.